# Pandas groupby with specified conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning Python/Pandas with a DataFrame having the following structure:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'brand' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'X', 'A', 'C', 'X', 'X', 'X']})

print(df1)

   unique_id brand
0          1     A
1          1     B
2          2     A
3          2     C
4          2     X
5          3     A
6          3     C
7          3     X
8          3     X
9          3     X
```

My goal is to make some calculations on the above DataFrame.

Specifically, **for each `unique_id`**, I want to:

- Count the number of brands without taking brand `X` into account;
- Count only how many times brand ´X´ appears.

Visually, using the above example, the resulting DataFrame I'm looking for should look like this:

```
   unique_id  count_brands_not_x  count_brand_x
0          1                   2              0
1          2                   2              1
2          3                   2              3
```

I have used the `groupby` method on simple examples in the past but I don't know how to specify conditions in a `groupby` to solve this new problem I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe first groupby `id` and later inside groups count `bands` and `X`

Comment: Have you looked at some guides/tutorials, the docs, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `merge`:

```
maskx = df1['brand'].eq('X')

d1 = df1[~maskx].groupby('unique_id')['brand'].size().reset_index()
d2 = df1[maskx].groupby('unique_id')['brand'].size().reset_index()

df = d1.merge(d2, on='unique_id', how='outer', suffixes=['_not_x', '_x']).fillna(0)
```

```
   unique_id  brand_not_x  brand_x
0          1            2     0.00
1          2            2     1.00
2          3            2     3.00
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `pd.crosstab` on True/False mask of comparing against value `X`

```
s = df1.brand.eq('X')
df_final = (pd.crosstab(df1.unique_id, s)
              .rename({False: 'count_brands_not_x' , True: 'count_brand_x'}, axis=1))

Out[134]:
brand      count_brands_not_x  count_brand_x
unique_id
1                           2              0
2                           2              1
3                           2              3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the original DataFrame and use the appropriate `groupby` operations for each calculation. `concat` joins the results.

```
import pandas as pd

s = df1.brand.eq('X')

res = (pd.concat([df1[~s].groupby('unique_id').brand.nunique().rename('unique_not_X'),
                  df1[s].groupby('unique_id').size().rename('count_X')], 
                 axis=1)
         .fillna(0))
#           unique_not_X  count_X
#unique_id                       
#1                     2      0.0
#2                     2      1.0
#3                     2      3.0
```

---

If instead of "unique_brands" you just want the number of rows with brands that are not "X" then we can perform a single `groupby` and `unstack` the result.

```
(df1.groupby(['unique_id', df1.brand.eq('X').map({True: 'count_X', False: 'count_not_X'})])
    .size().unstack(-1).fillna(0))
#brand      count_X  count_not_X
#unique_id                      
#1              0.0          2.0
#2              1.0          2.0
#3              3.0          2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first create groups and later count elements in groups

But maybe there is better function to count items in `agg()`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'brand' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'X', 'A', 'C', 'X', 'X', 'X']})

g = df1.groupby('unique_id')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['count_brand_x'] = g['brand'].agg(lambda data:sum(data=='X'))
df['count_brands_not_x'] = g['brand'].agg(lambda data:sum(data!='X'))

df = df.reset_index()

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:** If I have `df['count_brand_x']` then other can count

```
 df['count_brands_not_x'] = g['brand'].count() - df['count_brand_x']
```